# Orchard - Get path to media

Tags: orchardcms

Using Azure blob storage, if I upload a file with the media module, is there a way I can retrieve the path to that file in a View? I need to allow users to download a PDF by clicking on a link, but I don't know how to get the path to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use IStorageProvider. You could inject an IStorageProvider in the constructor for the Part's driver, get the path using the IStorageProvider interface, and pass it to the shape that you pass to the View in the part driver's Display() method.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds rather complicated. I was hoping for something as simple as an extension method provided by Orchard. :P

Comment: It may exist, but I haven't looked for it. Why don't you search to see if there are any extension methods that use IStorageProvider?

Comment: The only thing that seems to use it is the media module itself, but no extension methods. It must be pretty common to have to provide a link to a file, so I'm surprised you have to jump through so many hoops.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, there is very little documentation for the IStorageProvider, and there aren't many examples. I didn't find any extension methods that use it. Try looking at Orchard.Media.Services.MediaService. For more examples check out the 3rd party module, Piedone.Combinator.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at the MediaService class and the AzureFileSystem class, but not too sure how to go about using those to create an extension method. I'll have a look at that module, thanks.